# hiding "vendor" folder on shared hosting

Tags: php, composer-php

This is my first project in which I'm using Composer so I want to know a few things first that I haven't found while googling.

My current folder structure is this

```
functions
includes
vendors
composer.json
composer.lock
index.php
```

I'm using a shared web hosting and I'm working alone at this project. Should I upload all of this on my server ? Also how I can protect my `vendors` folder from giving away information about my dependences ?

Comment: Use an `.htaccess` (assuming you're on Apache) file to prevent public access to everything but the index.php file

Comment: @scrowler But if someone tries to read composer.json file ? They will know what to look for in vendors folder

Comment: *... to prevent public access to **everything** but the index.php file*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On many shared hosting you can setup your domain pointing to specified directory. You can than place in this directory only `index.php` and files that should be public (css, javascript, images etc.) and the real code of your application you put folder above, so the structure of your project could look like this:

```
vendor
includes
functions
composer.json
composer.lock
public_html
   index.php
   css/
   js/
   img/
```

now you should point your domain into `public_html`.